# Save and retrieve processed list in Django

Tags: python, django

I have one process list (like [["a","b","c"],["c","d","e"]]) in django and want to save such data in sql. I have built a class in model for such data as followed.

```
class Results(models.Model):
    batch_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    batch_cola = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    batch_colb = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    batch_colc = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I just want to know how could I edit the coding in the view.py function for save such list and retrieve such list? I need the retrieved data can still be like [["a","b","c"],["c","d","e"]].

Here's what I do but error appears as "table XX_result has no column named owner_id”.

```
    list 
    for t in list:
        Results.objects.create(batch_cola=t[0], batch_colb=t[1], batch_colc=t[2])
    data = Results.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return render(request, "projects/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

Comment: Can anyone kindly help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your problem.

Say we have a raw process list:

```
raw_process_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
```

And a Process model:

```
from django.db import models

class Process(models.Model):
    col_a = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    col_b = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    col_c = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here, are two Django helpers to save and retrieve such a list:

```
def save_raw_process_list(rp_list, user):
    for raw_process in rp_list:
        cols = dict(zip(['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'], raw_process))
        Process.objects.create(owner=user, **cols)

def retrieve_raw_process_list(user):
    return list(Process.objects
                .filter(owner=user)
                .order_by('id')
                .values_list('col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'))
```

Then, when you have to store a process list, simply write:

```
save_raw_process_list(raw_process_list, user)
```

And when you have to get it back:

```
raw_process_list = retrieve_raw_process_list(user)
```

Comment: Thx! this is quite helpful!